# Concern of Separations in MVC

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns

Everybody says that controller is application flow, model is business logic and view is the output.

I can understand that all templates (email templates, website template, SMS templates, JSON for ajax, etc) belongs to View. Also things like checking for user permission (e.g. in admin pages), routing request, etc belongs to controller. And actions like saving/retrieving/deleting data of database belongs to model. Finally, ViewModels are Classes that are called by Views to Get data from Models and VMs go to a folder beside Views, Models and Controllers.

But where should I put classes like Autoloader, Configuration, SendMail, SendSms, ReadMail, ReadSms, Auth, Request, Hash, Encryption, Validator, SessionHandler, ErrorHandler, CacheHandler, Notification, Chat, DB Migration, and a thousand others?

I'm looking for an ultimate guide: How detect that foo class belongs to M, V, C or VM, And in which folder/namespace put this?

P.S. I'm just looking for technology-indipendent standard. No matter how Laravel or ZF or any other frameworks out there implemented MVC.

Thanks.

Comment: MVC is a model of user interaction, it doesn't mean every and each class in your application falls into MVC.

Comment: Thank you @dmitry, are you saying that these classes should go in a separate folder/namespace like utility\Autoloader{} which utility is in same namespace level/folder as M, V, C and VM?

Comment: I mean that you may have any number of other code entities than anything you can fit into MVC. For example, Autoloader - what it does with MVC? Nothing, it loads classes, which is purely low-level task not related to the MVC architecture per se. The same for the most of classes you've provided in your question. They perfectly can go into separate folders and namespaces, but not necessarily. The particular naming and file layout choices are dependent on many concerns, but my main message was: not any class in your application is a part of MVC design.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can not nake this question without specifying which framework are you using. Although MVC is pretty much the same concept on every framework, framework implementations have certain differences.

Let's say you are using Laravel, in this case your routing preconditions as permissions or even being logged in or not will be implemented in a middleware that must be satisfied at the routes.php file.

Laravel sees models as the place to implement CRUD operations, but you are missing business logic that you may not have in the model, neither you want it in the controller. In that case you may create a separate context, a directory where you can store classes with code that will be used accross several controllers.

I would say even if you have full knowledge of the MVC pattern, you need to decide and study the framework to be used. Putting these 2 pieces together, will clarify where to place every bit of code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I want to create an small framework for my weblog and future projects, and I just wondering how to separate that classes.

Comment: if it is your own framwork, my suggestion is take classes as a separate container for all your reusable functionality that is not exactly a controller method. Most of the times controller methods are either point of entry for a route call, or auxiliary functions inside the method. If the code is to be used by multiple controllers, it smells like a separate class.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, So I must save these classes in a separate namespace/folder like utility\Autoloader, which utility is a folder/namespace with same level as M, V, C & VM, am I right? Is it ok to put classes like Autoloader that is used just by framework itself, and SendMail that is used by programmer in same namespace/folder?

Comment: Also, can you please tell me, classes that save/retrieve data, but doesn't work with database, like a class that uploads to/downloads from a remote url, UserUpload, File, Directory, etc belongs to \Model or \utility? Many resources on the web are saying that it is \Model, many others say \utility.

Comment: David, you are absolutely right, i would say you dont need to autoload most classes. You will use them on a need basis in some controllers. All you need to have is a well define path or namespace to locate them and some classes may require static methods to self instantiate. A good example would be a user class with an is_logged method.

Comment: Oh! I forgot ftp management, upload, download, those are not database CRUD methods, so yes, it goes as utility or helper classes.